# Logstash - Filter Syslogs by Keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, logstash-grok, syslog, grok

Im new to ELK, I have logstash storing syslogs generated from multiple network devices. All types of events are labelled on one facility (unfortunately) and I am only interested in storing the logs with DHCP leases. Below is a sample of the logs being stored by logstash

```
host:10.10.2.21 tags:_grokparsefailure type:dhcp @timestamp:May 6, 2020 @ 22:50:35.176 message:<190>May 6 22:50:33 10.7.24.13 Kiwi_Syslog_Server 2020-05-07 02:50:35 MOPS-E200E-CE-1 %%01SYSTATE/6/HEALTH(l): cpu=23 totalmemory=390127084 curmemory=176017096 @version:1 _id:gjYK7XEBLIinXt5dutFF _type:_doc _index:dhcp-2020.05.07-001 _score: -
host:10.10.2.21 tags:_grokparsefailure type:dhcp @timestamp:May 6, 2020 @ 22:50:33.727 message:<186>May 6 22:50:32 10.6.5.2 Kiwi_Syslog_Server May 7 2020 02:50:33 Data_Center-S9306-AS-1 OSPF/2/IFAUTFAIL:OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.14.16.2.6: A packet is received on a non-virtual interface from a router whose authentication key or authentication type conflicts with the local authentication key or authentication type. (IfIpAddress=10.4.0.254, AddressLessIf=0, ProcessId=3, RouterId=10.6.64.11, PacketSrc=10.4.0.44, ConfigErrorType=5, PacketType=1, InstanceName=) @version:1 _id:WzYK7XEBLIinXt5dtMzM _type:_doc _index:dhcp-2020.05.07-001 _score: -
host:10.10.2.21 tags:_grokparsefailure type:dhcp @timestamp:May 6, 2020 @ 22:50:32.478 message:<188>May 6 22:50:31 10.7.32.7 Kiwi_Syslog_Server date=2020-05-06 time=22:50:32 devname=MOTP_GT-FS248D-CE-7 device_id=S248DN3X17000508 log_id=0103034134 type=event subtype=system pri=warning vd=root user="alertd" msg="[First Event] TEMPERATURE_SENSOR_1 (49.0C) cleared warning threshold of (50.0C)." @version:1 _id:4jYK7XEBLIinXt5dsMg6 _type:_doc _index:dhcp-2020.05.07-001 _score: -
message:<134>May 6 22:52:29 10.7.24.23 Kiwi_Syslog_Server May 6 22:52:30 National-Trust-CE-1 PRESSDHCPSERVER assigned 172.18.20.24 to E8:93:09:CC:2A:C6 type:dhcp host:10.10.2.21 @version:1 @timestamp:May 6, 2020 @ 22:52:30.528 _id:jjgM7XEBLIinXt5dfFvH _type:_doc _index:dhcp-2020.05.07-001 _score: -
```

I only want to store the last line of log which have the DHCP information. I have observed that logs with DHCP information have the word "assigned" in them and so Im looking for a way for logstash to look for the word "assigned" and only store that line of log.

Below is my config for logstash

```
input {
  udp  {
    type => "dhcp"
    port => "518"
 }
}


filter {
 if [type] == "dhcp" {
   grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "assigned"
        }
    }

 }
}

output {
if [type] == "dhcp" {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
  index => "dhcp-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-001"
}
}
}
```

Could you please assist me, much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello Narendra Rajcoomar.

I am not 100% sure I got your question, so please correct me if I am wrong and I will edit my answer.

You are using the provided `logstash.conf` file and you get in elastic search the lines above, which also include events you are not interested in and you want ES to save only events that looks like the last line.

If that is correct, you may notice that all other events except the last line has a `tag` called `_grokparsefailure`. this is because indeed they don't include the "assigned" keyword, therefore they are not a "match".

Just change the `logstash.conf` output section accordingly and it will drop unnecessary logs:

```
input {
    udp  {
        type => "dhcp"
        port => "518"
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "dhcp" {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "assigned"}
        }
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "dhcp" and "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
        elasticsearch { 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
            index => "dhcp-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-001"
        }
    }
}
```